# How can I map a search in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm a Python programmer, and, by convention, methods starting with a `_` are private, and therefore should not be called outside of the class it belongs to.

I want a faster way for finding classes and public methods in Python (because I often have to dive into other people codes to investigate APIs), so I wrote a search, which is

```
/^    def [^_]\|^class
```

This works great when typed directly into Vim, but of course that takes too long to type. I'd like to map it to a key (say, `t`, since I don't use it at all in Vim as it is now). So, I put this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap t /^    def [^_]\|^class
```

But it's not working: when I hit the `t`, Vim searches for the string as it is, instead of parsing the special characters (which are, in this case, `^`, `[^_]` and `\|`).

Anyone knows how to write this mapping? I tried my luck in Vim Wikia, Google and all sorts of sources I could think of, no luck so far.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try tagbar plugin? it could give you overview of python script. function, class etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with `\|`: one layer of escaping is removed when `:nmap` itself is read, so you need another layer: use `\\` to say `\`.

```
nmap t /^    def [^_]\\|^class
# or maybe add a final <CR> key
nmap t /^    def [^_]\\|^class<CR>
```

Comment: Worked great! I'll accept your answer as soon as the mininum time is up! Plus one for the <CR>!